Gaussian-quadrature-rule and composite
Consider a numerical integration rule of the form $ \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \,dx\approx Af(-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}})+Bf(0)+Cf(\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}) $
Derive the composite quadrature rule resulting from the application of this rule to general integral  $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx$ on a uniform partition $x_{0}=a<x_{1}<\ldots,<x_{n}=b$ and derive the error term for the composite rule which should not contain any summations.
I first thought that this is Gaussian quadrature and I found the constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ by putting the polynomials $1$, $x$ and $x^{2}$ inside the integral and the degree of precision is 5.After finding as $A=\frac{5}{9}$, $B=\frac{8}{9}$ and $C=\frac{5}{9}$ I tried to convert the integral to an integral on [a,b]. As a result I obtained $\int_{-1}^{1}f((\frac{b-a}{2})t+\frac{b+a}{2})(\frac{b-a}{2})dt=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ and now I can compute $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx$ by writing $g(t)=f((\frac{b-a}{2})t+\frac{b+a}{2})(\frac{b-a}{2})$ and using $\int_{a}^{b}g(t)dt$=$Ag(-\sqrt(\frac{3}{5}))+Bg(0)+Cg(\sqrt(\frac{3}{5}))$ but I do not know how to generalize this to composite rule?  I researched on composite rule for Simpson s rule trapezoidal rule but I could not find any composite rule word for Gaussian quadrature I really need help to understand this concept and how to approach such a question.

Composite means you apply the basic rule to all sub-intervals $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ and sum up the results. The sum of all error terms can be replaced via the intermediate value theorem (or the mean value theorem for sums, similar to the integral one) to only have one term.

I do not get anything from your answer I am sorry

As you mention, the 'simple' rule is
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx \frac 59 g(-\sqrt{3/5})+\frac 89 g(0)+\frac 59 g(\sqrt{3/5}),
$$
where $g(t) = \frac{b-a}{2} f\left(\frac{b-a}{2} t + \frac{b+a}{2} \right)$. The error is given by
$$
E = \dfrac{(b-a)^7 (3!)^4}{7 (6!)^3} f^{(6)}(\xi) = \dfrac{(b-a)^7}{2016000} f^{(6)}(\xi),\quad \xi \in (a,b)
$$
The composite rule is obtained by dividing the original interval $[a,b]$ in sub-intervals and applying the rule for each interval. Taking $x_i = a + i h, i = 0, \cdots, n$ where $h = \frac{b-a}{n}$, we have that
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}f(x) dx \approx \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac 59 g_i(-\sqrt{3/5})+\frac 89 g_i(0)+\frac 59 g_i(\sqrt{3/5}) \right),
$$
where $g_i(t)= \frac{h}{2} f\left(\frac{h}{2} t + \frac{x_{i+1}+x_i}{2} \right)$. The error is now given by
$$
E = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{h^7}{2016000} f^{(6)}(\xi_i),\quad \xi_i \in (x_i,x_{i+1})
$$
Finally,using the intermediate value theorem,
$$
E = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{h^7}{2016000} f^{(6)}(\xi_i) = \frac{h^7 n}{2016000} \frac 1n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f^{(6)}(\xi_i)= \frac{(b-a) h^6}{2016000} f^{(6)}(\xi), \quad \xi \in (a,b)
$$
This process was perfectly summarized by Lutz Lehmann in his comment.

How did you derive the error?I can not get it now!!

I multiplied and divided by $n$ and used the fact that an average of values of $f^{(6}$ will be between the minimum and maximum of $f^{(6}$, hence it will be attained at some point.
